# быстрое удаление повторяющихся элементов в списке

Tags: python

Есть 2 списка (около 100000) элементов. Оба списка содержат элементы типа FirewallAddress

```
class FirewallAddress:
    def __init__(self, db_id, router_id, address, source_list_name, new_list_name, date):
        self.id = db_id
        self.router_id = router_id
        self.address = address
        self.source_list_name = source_list_name
        self.new_list_name = new_list_name
        self.date = date
```

как быстро найти уникальные элементы в списках по полю address?

p.s. set, но по полю класса

UPD: надо сделать функцию в которую подается 2 списка, надо вернуть элементы из первого списка которых нет во втором

Comment: Не совсем понял задачу. Что делать, если у нескольких объектов address окажется одинаковый?

Comment: @andreymal дописал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ответ [Stanislav Volodarskiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/416121/stanislav-volodarskiy) напомнил что в словарях поиск выполняется быстрее чем в листах. Вот решение:

```
def unique_addresses(from_addresses, in_addresses):
addresses = dict()
unique = []

for addr in in_addresses:
    addresses[addr.address] = addr

for addr in from_addresses:
    if addr.address not in addresses:
        unique.append(addr)

return unique
```

Answer (score 1):

Соберите адрес в словарь. Из словаря извлеките значения. Теперь они уникальные.

```
d = {}
for a in addresses:
    d[a.address] = a
unique = list(d.values())
```

Комментарий от [andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal) в одну строку:

```
unique = list({a.address: a for a in addresses}.values())
```

Comment: `unique = list({a.address: a for a in addresses}.values())`